# Spring Bean Creation Exception when Conflicts in Beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

The following is the code that is present in a common starter used in our project.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "some.prefix", value = "some-enable")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {
    SomeProperties.class,
})
@Configuration
class RabbitGenericValueConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public void setuoRabbit(AmqpAdmin admin) {
        admin.declareExchange(exchange());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "existing.property", value = "setup")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @Bean
    Exchange exchange() {
        return ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange(properties.getExchange())
            .build();
    }

}
```

In our service we need to create a custom exchange, however whenever we add the below code the following error happens

```
@Configuration
    public class CustomConfiguration {


        @Bean
        public DirectExchange direct() {
            return new DirectExchange("test.direct");
        }

    }
```

The exception is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'exchange' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:389)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at com.something.RabbitGenericValueConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2df2c1f1.exchange(<generated>)
    at com.something.RabbitGenericValueConfiguration.setuoRabbit(RabbitGenericValueConfiguration.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

The question is why does the application startup when the Custom exchange is not there and fail when the Custom exchange is there.

Comment: Because that is what you configured... You have `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` which will only add this bean if there is no other exchange defined. Now you define a `DirectExchange` which renders the `exchange` bean useless as there now already is an `Exchange` bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the `exchange` named bean such as :

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "existing.property", value = "setup")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@Bean
Exchange exchange() {
    return ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange(properties.getExchange())
        .build();
}
```

It sounds that the two declared beans derive from the `Exchange` class.  So the presence of the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation prevents the bean from being instantiated if this bean is instantiated first :

```
@Bean
public DirectExchange direct() {
    return new DirectExchange("test.direct");
}
```

As the [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) javadoc states (emphasis is mine) :

> Conditional that only matches when **the specified bean classes** and/or
>   names are not already contained in the BeanFactory.

You should probably remove `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` if you want that Spring  instantiates both.